# Instances running same tests in GitHub Actions for Cypress Cloud with parallelization

Tags: github-actions, cypress

I have this YAML code in GitHub Actions; how can I optimize the code so that each instance takes 30 different tests from the source folder out of a total of 90 tests path: `cypress/e2e/Tests` and does not allocate the tests between instances for Cypress Cloud with parallelization?

```
name: UP Automation regression

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  
  run-automation-regression-tests:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        instance: [1, 2, 3] # Define a matrix of 3 instances
    steps:
      - run: git config --global url."https://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@github.com/".insteadOf https://github.com/
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          persist-credentials: false
      - name: Cypress run
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v6
        with:
          browser: electron
          record: true
          parallel: true
          parallel-group-size: 30  # Specify the number of tests to run per group
          parallel-mode: "instance"  # Specify "instance" for Cypress Cloud execution
          record-key: ${{ secrets.CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY }}
        env:
          CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY: ${{ secrets.CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY }}
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

I tried the above workflow in GitHub Actions and I expected each instance to take the tests separately (for example the first instance tests 1-30, the second instance tests 31-60 and so on) but now they take my tests in the same way.

Comment: Looks like grouping is missing in your config. See https://github.com/cypress-io/github-action?tab=readme-ov-file#parallel. Also, `fail-fast: false` is also missing. See why it's needed in that note.